# Expectation of indicator variable squared

Tags: probability, random-variables

> Let $X$ be an indicator random variable with $P(X=1) = p$.

My understanding is that $E(X) = p$, but why is it true that $E(X^2)=p$ as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $X$ is an indicator random variable, $X$ only takes the values $0$ and $1$, so $X^2=X$.

Comment: Is it then correct to say that $E(X^k) = E(X)$ for any $k>=1$?

Comment: Yes, because $0^k=0$ and $1^k=1$.

Answer (score 3):

$$
\forall \alpha \in \mathbf{R}\setminus \{0\},\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\mathbb{E}[X^\alpha]= p\cdot 1^\alpha+(1-p)\cdot 0^\alpha=p.
$$